# Lookup tables in forms not displaying correctly in tables

Tags: ms-access

So, I had lookup fields on my tables. I have recently learned that this is a bad idea. So, I'm trying to convert them to lookup fields in the forms that fill those tables.

The lookup list is drawn from another table with the individual values. On the table, I went into design view under the lookup tag and changed "combo box" to "text box." The fields that were previously lookup fields now display the "key" of the item that was displayed previously in the field.

The form still shows the correct lookup value but the associated table no longer does it instead shows the number associated with the value and not the value. What do I need to do to fix this.

I guess my question boils down to not knowing how to link a lookup field in a form to a text field in a table.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change your forms, just update your tables - change lookup from combobox to text box, you did this correctly.

Existing forms should work as usual, with comboboxes, settings for those comboboxes were copied from table settings and not liked to table settings anymore.

In new forms you'll need to do the same manually: after placing the field to the form convert it to combobox then setup correct Row Source, Column Count and Column Widths properties of combobox.

Comment: I have a follow up question now. How do I handle the problem of lookups which allow multiple values? How can I get those lookups out of the tables and only use them in the form?

Comment: I would suggest to do not use multivalued table fields, this feature is buggy and almost useless. If you need to select more than one value, there is no built-in feature, which supports this, such kind functionality can be implemented using subform and it's not simple solution, requires additional tables and some VBA code

Comment: Would you mind pointing me in the right direction for getting that kind of functionality without using the multi-value fields?

Comment: This worked for most of my tables but there's one I'm having trouble with. I have one that is part of a relationship, when I try to change it to a text box, it starts to display a number instead of the name. The cell is configured as a number cell (which Access did automatically when I created it) When I try to change that to short text, it tells me I can't without deleting the relationship. If I delete the relationship then I end up with queries not working right.

Comment: Why you trying to change data type to short text in table? Data type of linked fields should be the same. You remove lookup in table only by changing to text. But in the *form* you should use combobox instead of default text, it should show related text instead of numbers after proper combobox setup. If you need multiselection, please create another question, it's quite complicated topic, too broad as you described

Comment: OK, here's what I did. I changed the value on the "lookup" tab on the table to "text box." The table immediately starts displaying the key for the related item from the form. The form is still set to "combo box" and displays the correct text for the associated items. If I change something in the form, the number changes in the table, I can't get it to display the text in the table. Are you saying I have an incorrect setting in the form? I've added some pictures to the original question in hopes that it will help. I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You should not see text instead of numbers in the table, this is absolutely normal. You see "raw" data used for linking between tables. If you need to manually edit the data, you should use forms and do not edit data in table directly

Comment: BTW here is explanation why using of lookup fields is not good practice: http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Comment: So the numbers are what I should see? Don't worry about it?

Comment: Yes, in table directly you should see numbers. Numbers used as IDs because search and comparing numbers is faster than strings and take less memory.